# How to stop reloading of Layoutpage on each partial page load in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i redirect to the partial page Layout page also got loaded. Why this is happening.My layout page contains below

```
   <a href="~/SuperAdmin/UserList" id="liUser">
     <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="menu-item"> Users </span>
   </a>
     <div class="wrapper">
           @RenderBody()
      </div>
```

And in SuperAdminController

```
  public ActionResult UserList()
        {   return PartialView();
            }
```

When I clicked on anchor tag, layout page reloaded along with the partial page userList.cshtml

Comment: Why do you not want the layout? But you can always use `@{ Layout = null; }` in the view

Comment: I just want to stop "reloading of layout" page. Layout page should remain and the only partial page should be loaded

Comment: What? Your making a redirect! If you just want the partial to be updated on the current page the use ajax to update the current page

Comment: So only the way is using ajax right!. Any other solutions?

Comment: If you only want to update part of the page, then ajax is your only option, but what are you concerned about?

Comment: I searched for, If there is any solution when I am using Razor and not using jquery ajax.. Thnaks for your replies

Comment: Read my previous comment!